# I want to program using two computers, how can I setup a working directory to accommodate that

Tags: netbeans, working-directory

I am using netbeans to write a program. I have come a long way writing different classes on one of two computers, however I need to use both on the same classes. My net beans directory is on dropbox. I set the projects working directory as

C:\Documents and Settings\damadr01\Dokumenter\Dropbox\Me, Myself & David\Activity_Calibrator

However this will mess up as soon as I try to run from the other computer. Is there a way of writing a relative wdirectory?

Comment: NetBeans itself has no needs for absolute paths, and your application should not need to have too. An application data path could be configured in the user Preferences. _Maybe you could elaborate a bit, what exactly is the problem. The synch with Dropbox causing build problems?_

Comment: @Joop Eggen I think that maybe what you have said could be the answer. My problem is that I write code in one place on a macbook and then on a windows pc later on, I always have to write the path to the file in java. I would like a way in which I could make this relative to the application itself but I dont know how to do that I will try what you are saying first though

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCS), like [git](http://git-scm.com/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [CVS](http://cvs.nongnu.org/) etc.

All of these have support on NetBeans. You can set the main repository on DropBox and clone repositories or working copies on a local folder. This way, you'll get the extra benefit of having the commit history.